# Should JQueryMobile apps have a php extension

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

In my job I have been ordered to make a dynamic application.Also, that all the pages should have a .php extension rather than a .html extension. I could strongly agree the php files will be needed for dynamic related subjects, but I just don't know why is a php file needed ?

Security? it's going to be view on mobile phones for the most part

Comment: I'm not sure even where to begin. PHP is Scripting language which requires a web server to parse and serve the files. What are you trying to build? Is it a website? A downloaded app using something like phone gap

Comment: And what does this have to with jQuery mobile? Which is a dom manipulation library meant for use on mobile web pages.

Comment: Good sir: I must strongly recommend you have a long and serious talk with your supervisor. The requirements you have been given do not make a great deal of sense, and I can therefore only conclude that there has been a terrible incident of miscommunication. Please confirm with your immediate superior the specifics and purpose of these demands, and return to us with an explanation, lest we lose hope in the basic tenets of human interaction which compose our living!

Answer (score 1):

Php pages give you the versatility and security to render pages how you WANT them to appear, without being affected by the user's browser version and/or settings. Also, it's much easier to dynamically create content when utilizing php over its alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

File extensions don't mean much.  The web server is configured to do *something* with certain extensions, but they could be anything really.  It has no security implications, and as far as the browser is concerned it's basically a vanity title.

I've built various applications that used unique extensions... such as a C# .NET web app which had two:  .portal was for web page requests, and .taj was for ajax requests.

Someone just likes .php I guess.

As for it being a jQuery mobile site, it sounds like they just want you to build it with PHP (and it must not be intended for Phonegap.)